# How do I add a socket to a fused alarm spur?

Tags: electrical

I am in the UK.

I wish to install a socket (possibly a double) in the under stair area of my house. The main consumer unit is based here and also the alarm box. One option would be to get an electrician to put in either a separate circuit (overkill) or split the downstairs ring at the consumer unit to provide a socket there, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

The other potential option is that the alarm is run off a fused spur. Is it acceptable/legal to run a socket off this fused spur? If so, should it be that I run it between the fused connection unit and the alarm or can I run two cables out of the FCU (basically in parallel)?

Comment: I have done a bit more reading around and I think this probably isn't the best idea. Primarily as the fused spur is likely to be less than the full 13A I would require for the socket (often alarm spurs are 3A).

In all likelihood it will be better to some how add a socket next to the consumer unit on the socket circuit - this is the idea, but I think logistically a bit more tricky due to cables disappearing straight under the floor (CU is only ~1ft off the floor).

Comment: convert that comment to an answer and I'll upvote you for it :)

Comment: the answer is true to the best of my knowledge. in america where i am and have been a journeyman electrican for 30 years. in the usa you cant put anything on a safety curcuit. would have to come off a cuircuit already or come all the way from your service panel. the wires are sized to the loads on branch circuits. so adding more load could turn your feeder wires into a fuse real quick.not smart and no electrican would. you can loose your license for doing dumb shit like that.

Answer (score 1):

The easy option is to install a radial circuit straight off the consumer unit, due to changes to the wiring regulations this circuit will need to be protected by a circuit level RCB device.
As a alteration to the electrical installation it would also need to be undertaken by a suitably qualified person. and  a Minor works certificate issued.

Failure to have a certificate could result in default on your home insurance.

Look for a NICEIC approved electrician who should be able to complete the works within a hour or two.